# How to make an Alexa skill read out JSON data (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an Alexa skill in which the Alexa device reads out the titles from the google news api. I have a [JSON url](https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=googlenews&sortBy=top&apiKey=5d7e436abbba47239eaf5b408c267792) and I'd like to make a function so that the title can be parsed out and read by the Alexa device. Here's my code so far: (it's missing the main function w/ JSON and stuff)

```
/**
 * App ID for the skill
 */
var APP_ID = undefined;
/**
 * The AlexaSkill prototype and helper functions
 */
var AlexaSkill = require('./AlexaSkill');

var News = function () {
    AlexaSkill.call(this, APP_ID);
};

// Extend AlexaSkill
News.prototype = Object.create(AlexaSkill.prototype);
News.prototype.constructor = News;

News.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionStarted = function (sessionStartedRequest, session) {

};

News.prototype.eventHandlers.onLaunch = function (launchRequest, session, response) {
    handleNewsRequest(response);
};


News.prototype.eventHandlers.onSessionEnded = function (sessionEndedRequest, session) {

};

News.prototype.intentHandlers = {
    "NewsIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        handleNewsRequest(response);
    },

    "AMAZON.HelpIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        response.ask("You can ask me for the latest news headlines in the world right now. Simply ask Top News for the latest news.");
    },

    "AMAZON.StopIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    },

    "AMAZON.CancelIntent": function (intent, session, response) {
        var speechOutput = "Goodbye";
        response.tell(speechOutput);
    }
};

/**
 * News API
 */
function handleNewsRequest(response) {
  /**
   * This is where I need help!!!!!!!!
   */







    // Create speech output
    var speechOutput =     ;
    var cardTitle = "Top News";
    response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, cardTitle, speechOutput);
}

// Create the handler that responds to the Alexa Request.
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    // Create an instance of the Top News skill.
    var news = new News();
    news.execute(event, context);
};
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are running into/question you have?

Comment: @httpNick I'm trying to parse data from a url so that I only have the title of the news articles. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request to the api and use that result in Alexa's tell function.

I would try using the [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to get the API data. The first example on the npm website should show you how to do that.

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
});
```

Because you'll need to wait for the response to come back, you will need to edit the function to also implement [Bluebird's Promisfication](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html). This will allow you to wait for the response before passing it to the tell function because it could take a few seconds to get a result from the API.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var Request = require("request");
Promise.promisifyAll(Request);

Request.getAsync(url)
.then(function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

Lastly, you will also need to use JSON.parse to get the value of the body that you need and use it on the tell function.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
response.tell(obj);
```